# Why are these two approaches to rotation giving me different UX?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

I implemented a custom subclass of `UIPageViewController` that is paging a few instances of another custom UIViewController subclass. Pretty standard. I don't and cant use autolayout.

I want to support rotation in this in these two cases

- ALL when all screen orientations are allowed in the app
- PORTRAIT ONLY when only portrait is allowed in the app.

When ALL orientation are allowed, everything works perfectly. Since the rotation is really a transform on  the window, all my custom paged controllers in the paging controller are "rotated" nicely (they simply resize to new bounds effectively), I am taking advantage of `viewWillTransitionToSize` and I am doing some custom layout to subviews via animating alongside. It's beautiful.

The second PORTRAIT ONLY case behaves not so beautifully. Since there is no rotation support in that case, I am listening to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification and I am rotating the root view manually.

I simply use UIView.animateWithDuration... and apply an affine transform to the root view of PagingController.

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.transform = self.rotationTransform()
        self.view.bounds = self.rotationAdjustedBounds()

        })
        { finished  in
    }
```

The transform is really a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation call in there.Nothing special. The `self` is the paging controller.

It works but for some reason the rotation is very ugly, it looks like anchor points are god knows where, and autoresizing masks for some of the subviews are not respected. This doesn't make any sense as the layout is done in a consistent manner, the proof being the rotation in the ALL case, everything adjusts to rotation perfectly.

I can't use an approach where I would allow rotation globally and then bail out to portrait everywhere except this controller. The app is huge, it's not possible from nontechnical reason, the stakeholders simply will not allow me to do that.

My question is - can you recommend a better approach given these constraints -> listening to Notification with manual rotation?

Comment: >  I don't and cant use autolayout. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, it is interesting to let other people know for reference.
I had to change two things:

**1) Trigger a layout pass** in the animation method

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.transform = self.rotationTransform()
        self.view.bounds = self.rotationAdjustedBounds()

        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
```

**2) Fix the actual layout convenience methods.**

Remember, I am doing layout manually. Those layout methods are all called from viewDidLayoutSubviews and only structure the code so that it is more readable, nothing special here. I made a silly mistake of calculating values like sizes and frame from other values...some of those other values were `.frame` properties. But frame is undefined when a transform is applied, so I changed all those occurrences to bounds instead.

It is now behaving i.e. rotating EXACTLY the same way as built-in rotations.

PS: I assume it worked nicely for built in rotation because there was no transform applied directly to the view. So there was no (root)view taking part in layout calculation that would have a transform applied on itself. Thats' why deriving values from the root view still worked.